# Eclipse JPA structure view, detail view, and persistence.xml editor not working?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, ide, jpa

Eclipse has pretty cool JPA Structure and JPA Detail views along with a persistence.xml editor and a JPA perspective.  However, I cannot seem to get them to "turn on".  I had them all working several months ago, but something must have changed.

Any tips as to what secret sauce is needed to get them working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug with Dali not understanding the Maven way of filter resources:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=251323

Who knows when this gets fixed, but I got around it by removing the "**" exclusion on my persistence module's resources directory in the build path.  I basically included Meta-Inf and excluded everthing else.

I then did a project->clean.

Hope this helps somebody....

Answer (score 1):

I don't really use [Dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) but if I recall correctly you need to add the **Java Persistence** Facet to your project (**right-click** on a project then go to **Properties > Project Facets** and select **Java Persistence**). Maybe have a look at the [Getting Starting](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/gettingstarted.php) guide.

Comment: This was a really good guess -- I had forgotten about project facets.  However, the JPA Persistence facet was already checked.  I unchecked it and applied, saw the "JPA Persistence" node in the project explorer tree disappear, then I rechecked it and it came back -- though still empty!!

Must be another setting somewhere....